# ApplicationSignInManager & ApplicationUserManager not found for Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

I am trying to use a SignInManager to verify (hashed) user passwords that are stored in a sql table, which were made with ASP.NET MVC controller, however when I try this through an ASP.NET Web API project, it cannot resolve either ApplicationSignInManager or ApplicationUserManager.

Is this the way to accomplish user verification, or should I be trying a different way?

```
    private ApplicationSignInManager _signInManager;
    private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;


    public ApplicationSignInManager SignInManager
    {
        get
        {
            return _signInManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationSignInManager>();
        }
        private set 
        { 
            _signInManager = value; 
        }
    }

    public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
    {
        get
        {
            return _userManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        }
        private set
        {
            _userManager = value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you install the ASP.NET Identity packages?

Comment: Yes, I installed Microsoft.AspNet.Identity Core, EntityFramework, and Owin but I still cannot get the type to resolve